# Search box that is similar to CTRL + F function

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to create a search box that is similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but only finds certain things.

When you type in something in the box "Skip to: " you will only be able to find names on the list below. I tried searching for it but I could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jquery autocomplete plugin
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Use a javascript array as a datasource. You could build the array dynamically by selecting the text of links that have a name attribute like `$("a[name]")`

When a suggested option is clicked/selected, you can use the select event to change the `document.location.hash` to the option value, so the browser will navigate to the anchor 
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select